# How can I avoid overfitting when doing parameter tuning?

Tags: machine-learning, overfitting, hyperparameter-optimization

I very often applied a grid search to tune the parameters of my supervised model. I have the feeling that parameter tuning will eventually (very often) lead to overfitting? Is this crazy to say?

Is there a way that we can apply grid search in such a way that it will not overfit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Usually you would use [cross validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) to avoid overfitting during parameter tuning. If your dataset is large enough, and you don't try *too* many parameter combinations, this will work well, because to "get lucky" and overfit, a parameter combination will need to work very well on *many* variations of the problem, which is less likely than working well on just one set of data.