# Can we say: the more we increase the numbers of cross validation the less likely it is that we overfit?

Tags: cross-validation

Based on the answer of my previous question:
[How can I avoid overfitting when doing parameter tuning?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/16038/how-can-i-avoid-overfitting-when-doing-parameter-tuning/16041#16041)

Can we say: the more we increase the numbers K of cross validation the less likely it is that we overfit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no.

There is a tradeoff between making the *validation set* for each fold smaller, and having more folds in total.

As an example, if you have $N$ folds for $N$ datapoints, each fold will have only a single datapoint in its validation set. The validation accuracy of a model on a single datapoint is not a reliable estimator for the test performance of the model. In fact, you can construct examples where the error is arbitrarily large.

For this reason, people sometimes use [Bootstrap Validation](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/32264/what-is-the-difference-between-bootstrapping-and-cross-validation) if they need a very large number of folds. In practice though, most people just us 10 folds, and that's "good enough".